# Error in jQuery when ListView returns no data

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, listview

I'm totally and utterly ignorant when it comes to jQuery so I need your help with changing the following script. This script remains in the Head of an aspx page. It works fine as long as ListView2 returns some data. If the listview2 is empty then I get an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." How can I change the script so that the function runs only when ListView2 is populated with data. Thanks

```
$(function () 
  {
    $("input[id*='checkbox1']").click(function () 
      {
        $("#<%=ListView2.FindControl("DeleteBackground").ClientID
                                %>").removeAttr('disabled');
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function () {
 $("input[id*='checkbox1']").click(function (e) {
   $("#<%=ListView2.ClientID %>").find("#DeleteBackground").removeAttr('disabled');
 });
});
```

Comment: I can't use the classname because many other controls on the page share the same name so I replaced tghe classname with the control ID and it worked well. Thank for the help.